# Finding the equation of the curve used to create a conical surface

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I'm given that the conical surface $f(x,y,z)=3x^2+3y^2+z^2-6xy-2xz+2x-1$ with apex the point $K=(1,1,1)$ and I'm asked to find the equation of the curve (not necessarily a circle) used to make the conical surface?

How do I handle this?

Also if I'm given both the equation of the curve and of the cone how do I find the apex?

Comment: there is no $yz$ term. Have you typed this correctly?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I also proved that it is indeed a conical surface by proving that there are $x_0,y_0,z_0$ such that $g(x',y',z')\equiv f(x'+x_0,y'+y_0,z'+z_0) $is homogeneous with respect to $ x',y',z'$. From this I found out the apex $A(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,1,1)$

Comment: it is a genuine cone rather than hyperboloid. The eigenvalues of half the Hessian matrix solve $ \lambda^3 - 7 \lambda^2 + 5 \lambda + 3 = 0,$ badly irrational values coming under Casus Irreducibilis, approximate $ \; -0.38318467, \; 1.2835369419, \; 6.0996477 \; . \;$ I do not see any good way to calculate the exact ratio of the two positive eigenvalues, which would tell you, at least, the ratio of semi-major axis to semi-minor axis in the ellipse orthogonal to the axis of symmetry.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Comment: Let's suppose that the eigenvalues weren't irrational. Could you briefly explain a way I could work to find the curve equation?

Comment: Then you can orthogonally diagonalize, $P^T P = I$ and $P^T H P = D$ diagonal. You can then write $au^2 + b v^2 - c w^2 = 0$ and the generating ellipse is, for example, $w=1$ and $au^2 + b v^2 = c.$ With a hyperboloid $au^2 + b v^2 - c w^2 = k,$ when $k > 0$ you get one sheet $au^2 + b v^2 = k + cw^2.$  When $k < 0$ two sheets.

Comment: In all three cases, the surface is made up of ellipses of identical eccentricity, in planes orthogonal to the axis of symmetry. In case $k \leq 0,$ the actual ellipses do not begin until $k +c w^2 > 0. $ For the cone, there is a single point that you call the "apex." For two sheets, there is empty space in the middle, then two points when $au^2 + b v^2 = 0$ exactly.

Comment: try this new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766872/analytical-3-dimensional-cone-geometry

Comment: "The curve used to make the conical surface" could be any section of the cone, in my opinion.

Comment: You’ve not given an equation of a cone. Do you mean the level surface $f(x,y,z)=0$?

Comment: Building on @Aretino’s comment, examine the intersections of the coordinate planes with this cone. One of them yields a simpler equation than the others.

Comment: I think Arentino and amd are right thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Giving the cone $f(x,y,z)=0$ choosing a non-tangent suitable plane

$$
\Pi\to ax+by+cz+d=0
$$

the intersection $f(x,y,z)\circ \Pi(x,y,z)$ gives a conic curve which can be used as supporting curve to create $f(x,y,z)=0$

In the present case we have

$$
f(x,y,z) = 3 x^2 + 3 y^2 + z^2 - 6 x y - 2 x z + 2 x - 1
$$

and choosing a plane as

$$
x+y+z=-15
$$

we have the intersection projection onto the $x\times y$ plane as

$$
224 + 62 x + 6 x^2 + 30 y - 2 x y + 4 y^2 = 0 = (p-p_0)M(p-p_0)+c_0
$$

with

$$
p=(x,y)\\
p_0 = \left(-\frac{139}{23},-\frac{121}{23}\right)\\
M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}6 & -1\\ -1 & 4\end{array}\right)\\
c_0 = -\frac{972}{23}
$$

[image]

NOTE

Choosing the plane $z = 0$ the intersection curve is given by

$$
3x^2+3y^2-6xy+2x-1=0
$$

which is a slanted parabola

Comment: why did you choose the plane $x+y+z=-15$ and then the plane $z=0$ can we use any plane?

Comment: Not any plane. You should avoid planes whose intersection give not closed conics as hyperbola or parabola. The plane $x+y+z=-15$ gives at the intersection a closed conic. An ellipse. This plane is a good one.

Comment: I see but how do I choose the plane? I mean how do I know if the intersection of the plane and cone give a closed conic?

Comment: Adopting a referential with the origin at the cone vertex, the cone will read $3 (X - Y)^2 - 2 X Z + Z^2=0$ so as can be observed, the line $Z = 0, X = Y$ is a cone line. Then choosing a normal vector $\vec n = (1,1,\phi)$ after some attempts we get a near optimum $\phi = 1$ defining a plane $\vec n\cdot(x,y,z) = x+y+z = \pm d$ with $d \ne 0$